# Should i use PHP to import CSS and JavaScript files to my page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Let's suppose we have two files `style.css` and `code.js`.

How should I import them into my html page? Which is the best way?

**Regular**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="code.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

**PHP way**

```
<html>
<head>
    <style><?php include_once "style.css"; ?></style>
    <script><?php include_once "code.js"; ?></script>
</head>
</html>
```

Which one is the most useful way of usage?

Comment: if you don't know the difference or which one is better, just use the regular way.

Comment: @AaronHarun you are right. It's just that some websites generate a lot of code this way and I thought that would be a better solution than the regular way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second way is a total mess, that will load the *entirety* of your CSS and JavaScript on each and every page load. If you want to blow up your bandwidth bill, this is how you do it.

The first way is how it *should* be done. This makes the content more easily cached, it means you can serve compressed assets without a lot of server overhead. It means you can dump those assets on a Content Distribution Network (CDN) and forget about them.

`include_once` is for PHP code, and *only* PHP code. Don't abuse it like this.

Comment: I did not abuse with it. Here is a snippet from google analytics PHP implementation. `<?php include_once("analyticstracking.php") ?>`

Comment: I have seen many websites, which instead of writing the easy `<link>` tag for stylesheets, import huge chunks of css code into the webpage

Comment: No, you're abusing it. Including a JavaScript snippet that way is not abuse since the content is more minimal. The Google analytics code is usually 5-6 lines, maximum.

Comment: Put down the shovel and stop digging yourself a deeper hole here. This pattern of including everything on every page is **wrong** on a number of levels. You should also use [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) for inlining a section of code from an external file. "I've seen it done" is not validation. I've seen a lot of things in my career and many of these things are super bad ideas.

Comment: What if i change `include_once "..."` to `echo getfilecontents()`? Would i be abusing less then?

Comment: @IchHabsDrauf For tiny snippets of JavaScript, like your Google analytics example, it's not a terrible idea. For the entirety of the site CSS and JavaScript it's the worst idea ever. Don't do it.

Comment: No, because loading css and js as anything other than a external file kills the ability of the browser to cache the data.  If you include it in the html/php you're needlessly and wastefully re-sending that data each time you load a page

Comment: thanks for the responses. I just don't realise why other big websites generate big amounts of code inside their webpage if this is a bad idea like u guys r saying.

Comment: Most browsers have some kind of developer mode where you can see how much data you're downloading and how large your pages are. Watch how crazy huge they get when you inline the CSS on every page. Use tools like [YSlow](http://yslow.org) to give advice on how to optimize your pages.

Comment: @todman fine i give up

Comment: @IchHabsDrauf Don't give up, look into how it plays out if you try the two different approaches. There's reasons why people don't do this and it's best to understand them rather than just blindly adhere to advice people give you.

Comment: @tadman this is the wisest thing i have heard for a long time. thank you so much for your advice.

Comment: I agree with your conclusion @tadman, but the answer could be a little clearer about how the two approaches look from the browser's point of view. (I'm just thinking how a beginner stumbling onto this question might not understand that the second way includes everything inline.)

Comment: @nnnnnn Some things are left "as an exercise for the reader".